# single-word noun for an immoral person

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single-word noun for an immoral (**edit**: just as likely, *amoral*) person. The closest I've come up with are: *deviant*, *scoundrel*, and *reprobate*. None of those seems harsh enough. Are there better options?

An example sentence, although not the writer's actual content, would be something like this:

> She tried to appeal to his better nature, but he was a(n) XXX and had none.

I've tried looking in various places for combinations of *noun* and *immoral person*, but none of them yielded much more than the above.

(**Edit** based on comments: *Scoundrel* and *reprobate* have some of the right feel, as does *boor*, but they are used playfully too often to capture it correctly.  *Blackguard* and *miscreant* are perhaps better, and they may be the best that I can find.  I think the trouble is that I was looking for *immoral*, when I should probably have been looking for *amoral*, but *sociopath* feels too much like a diagnosis.  I will run this by my daughter, who was the one looking, and is probably asking in her writers groups, but I'm starting to believe I was overthinking this.  I'm looking for a word for someone whose amorality makes me think the person is immoral.  And at that point, perhaps the simple *monster* will do; although that is more judgmental than desired.  I'll run *blackguard* by her.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152150/discussion-on-question-by-scott-sauyet-single-word-noun-for-an-immoral-person); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can slightly reword, a *scoundrel* is someone who is **unscrupulous**.

> without moral principles; not honest or fair

The slight rewording simply drops to article so an adjective can be used.

> She tried to appeal to his better nature, but he was <strike>a(n)</strike> *unscrupulous* and had none.

[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/unscrupulous)

Comment: Thank you.  This is actually not for me, but for my daughter, whose structure really calls out for a noun; my sentence was just an example because the `singe-word-request` tag recommended one.  There are many, many good related adjectives.  `Unscrupulous` would be quite fitting, if an adjective actually fit.  But I'm still hoping for a noun, and am surprised by how few there seem to be.

Comment: Scoundrel really is the noun counterpart--a scoundrel is an unscrupulous person. The lack of harshness might be due to these words being commonly used in a facetious way in the past.

Comment: Yes, that's my objection to *scoundrel*; it's too often used lightheartedly, even flirtatiously, which is entirely the wrong vibe.

Comment: *Unscrupulous* may cover many immoral people, but not all: some people commit horrendously immoral acts because they scrupulously follow their own misguided ideas about what they ought to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Reprobate** seems to work. It is a noun, although it may lack the connotation your daughter is looking for in the sentence. It does seem to be used with affection much of the time, like rogue or rascal.

Perhaps **villain** would work?

Comment: Thanks.  She's already rejected *reprobate*, but I'll run *villain* by her.

Answer (score 1):

I like the way **fiend** sounds here.

Fiend

> a wicked or cruel person (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fiend)

> She tried to appeal to his better nature, but he was a fiend and had none

Comment: Unattributed text is indistinguishable from plagiarism. Please fix your missing attribution.

Comment: @tchrist Ah, thank you for the heads up. I see now the other posts have the dictionary link.

Comment: I like it.  I'll run this one by my daughter as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'someone whose amorality makes me think the person is immoral' so can't help you there, but deviant, scoundrel, reprobate, degenerate, etc. all have similar meaning and would work in your sentence pretty much interchangeably.  Those words are generally NOT used playfully.  If you want something more harsh (and colloquial) you could go with scumbag, asshole, jerk, etc. or a whole host of similar putdowns too numerous for a Thesaurus.

Answer (score 0):

There's **psychopath**, someone with no conscience or "better nature". Virtually every dictionary on the planet will say something along those lines, perhaps using words like "who never feels remorse".

You can find similar views on what a psychopath is by perusing some of the excerpts **[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22psychopath%20is%20someone%20who%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=286f218df0db1919&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1246&bih=638&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0913QZ59o3kdEErx14UDEh_45n3rw%3A1711035088346&ei=0FL8ZYXRFJmg5NoP4IyOyAY&ved=0ahUKEwiF-Y211oWFAxUZEFkFHWCGA2kQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22psychopath%20is%20someone%20who%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhsicHN5Y2hvcGF0aCBpcyBzb21lb25lIHdobyJInmBQmwVYvV1wAHgAkAEAmAF9oAGhHaoBBDQ5LjK4AQPIAQD4AQGYAgOgAoYCwgIFEAAYgATCAgQQIRgKmAMAiAYBkgcDMi4xoAelOg&sclient=gws-wiz-books)**.

Comment: This was flagged as LQ.  You know what to do to stay out of the queue.

Comment: Sorry, was this the original and you edited it to include the link to MW?

Comment: @Lambie I believe livresque edited it because we require answers to single word requests to include a citation from a reliable source (usually just a copy-pasted dictionary definition).

Comment: @alphabet Yes, I know that but I want *them to answer*. People who edit don't usually completely change the thing. Had I been livresque, I would have worded my comment differently.

Comment: *sociopath* is closer to what I'm looking for than *psychopath*, but thank you.  The more possible terms I can find, the more jumping-off points I have in the thesaurus hopping.

Comment: I thik this requirement to paste in a dictionary definition is stupid. It should be necessary only if the answerer has misconstrued the definition and is challenged by another user to justify the answer. If the answer fits and you know it fits, upvote it.  If you think it is a wrong answer, downvote it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Had your sentence said something other than "... but he had *none*" then I would have suggested **sociopath**. With a sociopath there's a shred of hope for redemption  :-)

Comment: Also, as far as Merriam-Webster is concerned, pasting their content here would be a violation of their Terms of Service.

Comment: @TimR Quotations are always considered fair use under copyright law. This is just a special case of the more general policy requiring answers to include citations from reliable sources.

Comment: @alphabet Not when they're pasted into a commercial site. Lifting a dictionary''s definition is not a fair-use.  It's a dumb policy to require users here to copy and paste a dictionary definition rather than simply saying "(see M-W, or see OED 3.4 or something like that)".

Comment: @TimR I'm not a copyright expert, but I'm about 99% sure this is nevertheless fair use. That said, plenty of users on (say) grammar or usage questions don't bother to cite *any* sources; I dislike this (particularly when the answers seem highly subjective) but I may be fighting a losing battle, in which case we should probably lift this requirement everywhere.

Comment: @alphabet  I think people should challenge answerers to defend an answer with citations whenever they see fit, especially if they disagree with it, but if something is common knowledge and could be easily supported with dozens and dozens of references, such as the meaning of the word **psycopath**, it should suffice to have upvotes or downvotes be the judge. Why even have a voting system?

Comment: No, pasting MW content and saying it comes from Merriam Webster is not a violation of terms of service. It is free advertizing for them. Read some Scotus documents.

Comment: @Lambie: "we're giving you free advertizing" is not a defense.

Comment: It's an added benefit to them. If you state the name of the dictionary, that is really all you have to do. Pasting MW's content and attributing it is certainly not a violation of copyright  law or their terms of service. What an idea. In academic papers you would give the whole long attribution. And alphabet is right here about fair use.

Comment: However, all words in MW have copy citation at the bottom of the page: “Democracy.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy. Accessed 21 Mar. 2024.

Copy Citation

Comment: @Lambie  MW says you may "reproduce... content...only for your personal, non-commercial use. If you are a teacher, scholar or student, you may copy reasonable portions of the content...for lesson plans, interactive whiteboards, reports, dissertations, presentations, school newspapers and for similar nonprofit educational purposes to the extent permitted by applicable law. ... If you want to reproduce or use content ... in any manner other than as described above, including for purposes of developing or training AI or to conduct computer analysis, you will need Merriam-Webster's permission."

Comment: Reproduction here is for non-commercial use. If you think citing dictionaries here is an issue as you seem to think it is, post that as a META question since you don't believe me. They'll [those who answer] will tell you.

Comment: From the SE terms of service: "...any and all content...that you provide to the public Network ...is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display **and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content**, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you..."  [my emphasis]